# Best practices approach to multiple views in meteor?

Tags: meteor

Every tutorial/example i can find for meteor shows a single view application. I would like to build something a little more complex. I'm unclear how to approach multiple views...preferably in a way that's somewhat scalable?

Comment: Summary: [use iron-router](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14740242/1269037)

Answer (score 7):

The [iron-router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) package lets you access different views (layouts) by nice, REST-ful [human-friendly clean URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL). It supports parameters in the URL, "loading" templates, waiting for subscriptions to finish loading, `before` and `after` hooks etc.

Answer (score 3):

At this point you can only create Single Page applications with Meteor. Note that Single Page, doesn't mean you can't have several views - use [iron-router](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14740242/1269037) for that.

But by design, Meteor serves a big fat unique JavaScript/HTML/CSS application down to the browser, though there's a feature request to allow [incremental loading](https://trello.com/c/24s6vyxo/55-incremental-loading). It is then up to the application (or more precisely, the JavaScript framework), to dynamically render its views in order to display different "pages".

Comment: For now I've set a session variable and render views (templates) based on it's value. It works for the relatively simple app I've created, but feels a bit sloppy :)

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering the same thing and it took me way too much time getting something started.  I finally got a paged app working solidly by using Backbone views and routes, so I created a simple boilerplate project to make setting up an app like this easier in the future.

Live demo here: [backbone-boilerplate.meteor.com](http://backbone-boilerplate.meteor.com/)

Source code here: [github.com/justinmc/meteor-backbone-boilerplate](https://github.com/justinmc/meteor-backbone-boilerplate)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [madewith.meteor.com](http://madewith.meteor.com)?

A bunch of apps there have multiple views using Backbone also Jonathan Kingston who created [britto](http://github.com/jonathanKingston/britto) has started simple meteor framework called [Stellar](http://github.com/jonathanKingston/stellar)

At this stage of the game not sure if there really are best practices. But these two seem to be the current flow.

Comment: You are missing the point. Meteor are single page applications. that works fine for simple apps. If you have a very large ui application it will certainly be an issue.

Comment: I understand your point Oliver but complex doesn't have to mean big fat file also gzip takes a huge file and squashes it flat to every modern browser so big fat is no tiny tim. Also gmail is a single point app with #views not requiring full page refresh. I agree it's not small but to to slow either.

Comment: This answer is pretty [deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14740242/1269037) by now. Would be nice to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a tabbed interface for multiple views. There is a package project "Smart package for generating a tabbed interface with pushState" github project here: https://github.com/possibilities/meteor-tabs

Answer (score 0):

The best solution right now is using a routing package (router is basic but works). The workflow is something like this:

- declare routes; return a template name for each route
- place the reactive helper provided by the package in your body tag
- the reactive helper will return the template associated to that route
- you create a template for each route and optionally set custom publish functions

Router will give you browser history (client side).

Note that at this time there are some limitation on the way Meteor handles html/js. They are load all at the same time. The bright side is that once the app is loaded, page transitions will be instant.